# Getting error, while adding TFS service account to the attached database from different environment

Tags: sql, tfs

Till now we restored configuration database and collection database, then we ran the TFS Config Remap, Prep Clone and change server id. Now I can able to add the configuration database while running app tier only wizard and getting an error

> **"TF254006: No usable accounts are present in your confirmation database. Use TfsConfig accounts/add to add an account and return to this wizard".**

We are getting below error while adding TFS Service account to the attached database from different environment as part of TFS archival/splitting process.
 **TfsConfig Accounts /add /AccountType:ApplicationTier /account: AccountName /SQLInstance: ServerName /DatabaseName: DatabaseName**

> **Error : TF400794: No connection string found for database category 'warehouse'**

Comment: Could you describe what are you trying to do? What have you done?

Answer (score 1):

`/SQLInstance: ServerName` and `/DatabaseName: DatabaseName` used only with `/ResetOwner`, they are not supposed to use with `/add`.

Add the account to the service account groups for Team Foundation Server. You can simple use:

```
TFSConfig Accounts /add /AccountType:ApplicationTier /Account:AccountName
```

[image]

Comment: Am getting below error, after executing above command

TF400919: For the Add operation both /sqlInstance and /databaseName parameters h
ave to be specified pointing to the configuration database.